# Website traffic tracking integration

Tags: javascript, api, grails

I am looking to integrate simple web traffic tracking with a grails app.

I was thinking the best way to do this is with JavaScript include at the end of each page, kind of like Google analytics and many others do it, so it's not server log specific (our app is clustered over multiple servers). When it comes to reporting results, I need a very simple counter of unique visits based on page URL retrieved through an API so it can be pulled with REST preferably.

Before I dive into throwing up a custom app for that, wanted to see if you can recommend any existing solutions, something free to use / cheap ...

Thanks

Comment: Why not use one of the existing solutions built precisely for this like Google Analytics or StatCounter or others?  They have done a lot of cross-browser work for you already and do not cost much to use, particularly for a business.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I would much rather not reinvent the wheel and if you read my last sentence, that is exactly what I am looking for, recommendations for some products. Google, however, does not offer real time stats, they are delayed. StarCounter has no api so I will not be able to pull data into my app

Comment: Google are beta testing [realtime analytics](http://www.davidnaylor.co.uk/google-analytics-realtime-webmasters-tools-integration.html). Hopefully it will be public soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going with http://piwik.org/

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a long shot, if you really don't have to user JS you could just add your own taglib to each site that keeps track of whatever you wan to track...